# Python coroutines gives unknown None on yield

Tags: python, yield, coroutine

i'm trying to build a pipeline of some math operations, based on user input and try to print the acumulation result for this operations.
For example the input would be a list of operations, then the number of numeric inputs and then numbers like this:

```
[square, accumulate]
3
1
2
3
```

This should return something like:

```
1
5
14
```

First it prints 1 as 1*1, then it adds up that 1 to the result of 2*2 giving 5, then adds it to the 3*3 giving 14.
But there's something wrong with my approach, the second number input always turns into a None value and I don't know why.
I'm stuck getting:

```
1
None
10
```

Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def printer():
    while True:
        x = yield
        print(x)

def co_generator(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        x = int(input())
        yield x

def get_root():
    while True:
        number = (yield)
        yield math.floor(math.sqrt(number))

def get_square():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number = (yield)
        yield number**2

def accumulator():
    acum = 0
    while True:
        acum += (yield)
        yield acum

def operations_pipeline(numbers, operations, print_acum):
    for num in numbers:
        for i, w in enumerate(operations):
            num = w.send(num)
        print_acum.send(num)
    for operation in operations:
        operation.close()
    print_acum.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order = input().strip()
    n = int(input())

    numbers = co_generator(n)

    print_acum = printer()
    next(print_acum)

    root = get_root()
    next(root)

    accumulate = accumulator()
    next(accumulate)

    square = get_square()
    next(square)

    operations_pipeline(numbers, eval(order), print_acum)
```

Comment: What inputs exactly did you use to get that result?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the `x = yield;
        print(x)` for?

Comment: What do you think all those `(yield)`s yield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing your code as if `(yield)` receives a value and `yield whatever` sends one. That's not how it works. **All `yield`s both send a value and receive one.**

When a generator executes a `yield`, it does so in two phases. First, the argument of the `yield` becomes the return value of the current `next` or `send` call, and the generator suspends execution. If there is no argument, `None` is used. That's where your `None`s are coming from

Second, when another `next` or `send` is executed, the generator unsuspends, and the `send` argument (or `None` if `next` was used) becomes the value of the `yield` expression.

You're trying to use one `yield` to receive a `send` argument and another to set `send`'s return value. You need to use a single `yield` to set a `send` return value and receive the next `send`'s argument. For example,

```
def get_square():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number = yield number**2
```

Alternatively, if you want to use separate `yield`s to send and receive values on the generator's end, then you need to use separate `send` (or `next`) calls to receive and send values on the other end, and ignore the `None`s. For example,

```
w.send(num)
num = next(w)
```

instead of `num = w.send(num)`, so `operations_pipeline` would look like

```
def operations_pipeline(numbers, operations, print_acum):
    for num in numbers:
        for w in operations:
            w.send(num)
            num = next(w)
        print_acum.send(num)
    for operation in operations:
        operation.close()
    print_acum.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes from all the examples I've seen I thought that one yield recieves and another one sends, but I think I understand now how things work. Every action after the yield will run until the next time send it's called, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
def rooter():
    number=0
    while True:
        number= yield math.floor(math.sqrt(number))
    

def squarer():
    number=0
    while True:
        number= yield number**2
```

> yield will give none try this way

```
def accumulator():
    number=0
    while True:
        number+= yield number
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a call to `next` in your `operations_pipeline` code here:

```
def operations_pipeline(numbers, operations, print_acum):
    for num in numbers:
        for i, w in enumerate(operations):
            num = w.send(num)
            next(w) # <<<--- this
```

Without that I don't believe it was ever getting back into `get_square` the second time, assuming your first input was `[square, accumulate]`.